# How to initialise state stored in separate components from a single async request?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

#### What I would like to do:

- I have various self-contained components, that manage their own state within themselves. The state of each component should definitely be handled within each component.
- Their initial state comes from the back-end. After this they maintain their own state.
- I don't want to make lots of separate requests for each component, so I make one request to fetch the data for all of the components, and pass this down which provides initial data for each component.

#### My current Solution:

```
const MyApp = () => {
    const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState();
    useEffect(()=>{getInitialState().then((data)=>{
        setInitialState(data);
    })},[])
    if (!initialState) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    return (
        <>
            <ComponentA initialData={initialState.A} />
            <ComponentB initialData={initialState.B} />
            <ComponentC initialData={initialState.C} />        
        </>
    )
}
```

#### Problems with my current solution:

The above works, but it doesn't feel right. I've called the above `initialState` but it shouldn't be state. It's much more like a prop, and it's confusing to store the initial data for the entire life-time of the app. Admittedly, it's not doing anything, and doesn't cause any harm, but if it's not being used by anything, why keep it there?

I considered fetching the data before I even rendered the app, and then passing the data in as a prop, but then I would have nothing displayed rather than a loading screen, so that didn't seem like a good approach either.

#### My Question:

Is there a better (and/or standard) approaching for achieving the above? (I'd like to use hooks rather than classes). Perhaps the above isn't such a bad idea, but it feels like there must be probably a better way of doing it without resorting to 'global' app state. I would like to keep my state close to the components where the relevant parts of it are used.

Comment: If you use redux, redux-persist is a good choice. It saves only those reducers that you want and it works faster than async requests to re-store the state.

Comment: I think you need a state management layer, to hold a global app context. Redux or Mobx, or maybe just React Context API could help you to hold a global state in one place, where components could find what they need. I could elaborate in an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using state here. However, assuming that `getInitialState` is only supposed to be called once, I would wrap it in the `useEffect` hook, such that the data is only fetched once when `MyApp` is mounted. This will prevent `getInitialState` from being called repeatedly when the component re-renders.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getInitialState().then((data)=>{
    setInitialState(data);
  });
}, []);
```

If you do not wish to use state to maintain the data, you will have to rely on the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), or use some kinda state management library such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Comment: gah, sorry. I was typing the question not using my actual code and forgot the useEffect hook. Yes, that is what I was doing. I've updated the question. Thankyou for your feedback about state though :)

Comment: To clarify what I mean in the question. It's not that I don't want to rely on state. I just want the state to be stored further down the tree, closer to where the state is actually used.

Comment: Got it!! In that case, I think you might want to have state management then. If you do not want to use Redux due to the excessive boilerplate that comes along with it, you can use something lighter such as MobX (next best solution), or Recoil (it is clean, but it is still experimental).